# Google wiki to Eclipse help conversion possible? Which tools?

Tags: eclipse, wiki, converters

is there a way to generate Eclipse help files from Google wiki pages as it is possible to generate such ones from twiki or mediawiki pages via the mylin wikitext plugin?

Or are there converter available to bring google wiki files into mediawiki or twiki format?

In hope for help,
omnaest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it seems that anyone has an idea, I created an own ant task for text file conversion.

If there is interest in an example of converting textile pages into google wiki pages you can look at
[ant script example](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/javadocasumlview/source/browse/#svn/trunk/helpSrc_ant_script)

There is the ant task used to convert textile pages into html and google wiki and then to deploy.

The important ant target of the buid.xml is "convertWikiFolder" and it looks like:

```
<target name="convertWikiFolder" depends="dircopyWikiFolder">
  <echo message="Converting textile files for wiki folder."/>
  <textFileContentConverter fileNameSource="${folderWikiTarget}" fileNameRegexFilter="(.*)\.textile$" fileNameReplacement="$1.wiki" fileNameRegexFilterAndReplacementPatterns="regexFilterFromTextileToGoogleWiki.xml" deleteSourceFileAfterConversion="true"/>
</target>
```

It uses the "regexFilterFromTextileToGoogleWiki.xml" to define regular expressions which translates the different wiki/text syntax.

To convert other wiki syntax files this regex file has to be adapted.

The related ant task binary is located under "bin/TextFileContentConverter-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar"

Answer (score 0):

Google wiki pages aren't directly supported by Mylyn WikiText.

For MediaWiki take a look at the Eclipse documentation on [MediaWiki To Eclipse Help](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.help.ui/help/Markup-Conversion.html#MediaWikiToEclipseHelp) which provides an Ant task for generating Eclipse Help from a MediaWiki.  Also [DocumentationGuidelines/CrowdSourcingExample](http://wiki.eclipse.org/DocumentationGuidelines/CrowdSourcingExample) provides a concrete example of how this can be done.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I already mentioned this in the question itself. The ant task of my answer adds the missing step of the translation of google wiki to media wiki or textile syntax